# How can I read a text file with a custom extension using p5js

Tags: javascript, upload, p5.js

I want to load text files of a custom extension from disk using p5js, preferably with `createFileInput()`. I can save a text file of a given custom extension using `createWriter()`, which I can then access and read with no problems on my default notepad. The problem I'm facing occurs when trying to load said text file using `createFileInput()`, which leads to a file of .type `""` instead of the desired `"text"`. For example,

```
function setup() {
  load = createFileInput(loadFile)
  noCanvas();
  let content = 'Hello World';
  let writer = createWriter('saveFile.ctxt');
  writer.write([content]);
  writer.close();
}

function loadFile(file) {
  console.log(file.type, file.data);
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.4.1/p5.js"></script>
```

Outputs `""  data:application/octet-stream;base64,SGVsbG8gV29ybGQ=` when loading saveFile.ctxt, which I can't comprehend at all.

Desired output is `"text"  Hello World`, regardless of the custom file extension used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) and the [`FileReader.readAsText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText) method, taking care to pass `file.file` from the p5.js callback into it.

[`file.file`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5.File/file) is the "underlying `File` object. All normal `File` methods can be called on this".

```js
let fileInput;

function setup() {
  noCanvas();
  noLoop();

  // Used to create the file:
  // (probably won't work in Stack Snippet)
  //const writer = createWriter("saveFile.ctxt");
  //writer.write(["Hello World"]);
  //writer.close();

  fileInput = createFileInput(file => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = e => {
      console.log(e.target.result); // => Hello World
    };
    reader.readAsText(file.file);
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.5.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you were to pass a .txt file to the input, `file.data` will have the result text already, without the need for the `FileReader`.